# how to randomly select a file in a directory open it and write into it?

Tags: python

I am trying to randomly select a file in folder open it and write into it. 
I have:

```
import os, random
x = random.choice(os.listdir("F:\\1\\"))
y =open(x, 'w')
y.write('Hello World')
```

but nothing gets written. any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: you're picking the filename, not the full path. This is a dangerous thing you want to achieve btw

Comment: `y.close()` somewhere?

Comment: A tip though, avoid `open()` and `close()`. Use `with open(filename) as ...:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very dangerous, as you opening a `file` for `writing` `blanks` it of all its content, so you are effectively `randomly` destroying one `file`.

Anyway, if that is what you want, use a `with` statement and remember that `os.listdir` returns the `file` `names` in a directory, not `paths`, so you need to use `os.path.join` to join the `2` parts together:

```
import os, random
path = r"F:\1"
x = random.choice(os.listdir(path))
with open(os.path.join(path, x), 'w') as y:
   y.write('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not closing the file:

```
import os, random
x = random.choice(os.listdir("F:\\1\\"))
y =open(x, 'w')
y.write('Hello World\n') 
y.close()
```

Comment: no it's not the issue. it's _an_ issue, but one of the files would be truncated anyway. The issue is that the full path isn't passed. it creates the file in the current directory instead of in the original dir

Answer (score 0):

The `os.listdir` command lists all files in the given directory. It does *not* prepend the path (the directory name). You therefore have to do

```
import os, random
dirname = "F:\\1\\"
x = dirname + random.choice(os.listdir(dirname))
y = open(x, 'w')
y.write('Hello World')
```

Also, it is good practice to close a file once you are done writing to it. You can do this by `y.close()`. This is done for you automatically if you use a `with` statement like so:

```
import os, random
dirname = "F:\\1\\"
x = dirname + random.choice(os.listdir(dirname))
with open(x, 'w') as y:
    y.write('Hello World')
```